# Access dygraphs series without the series label

Tags: dygraphs

I just found out that I can add two different labels under the same label - that's pretty nice, since it cleans up the mouse-over legend. They even have the same color, so it's clear to see that they belong together.

However, I would still like to change the options of one of the series separately. Is this possible? E.g. can I access the series options via indices?

For example: I do have a theoretical function and some measured data points - they belong together, so they have both the label "Condition 1" (as an example). This works fine, but now I would like to have a different plotter for both (so that my function can show a line, and the measured points are drawn as points). Obviously I can not change the per series options via "Condition 1", since it would change both series.

Is it possible to still access them seperately, or do I have to set 2 separate labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The [per-series options syntax](http://dygraphs.com/per-axis.html) won't allow this. To be honest, I'm surprised that having two series with the same name does anything sensible at all! If there's a behavior there, it's by accident, not by design.

Comment: I was surprised too, happend by accident - and then I thought: Wow, awesome ;) Well, not too big of an issue, thanks for the clarification!